# Why does sqlite3_prepare_v2 == FALSE?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, xcode4.3

Not sure why sqlite3_prepare_v2 equals false. I've searched around online and couldn't find much and what I did find didn't help. One site suggested to using sqlite3_errmsg(database) and this outputted "not an error" for some reason. Another answer online suggested deleting a folder in the iPhone simulator which is named with a string hex, but that didn't work either. I made my database and dropped into the supporting files folder so it is there and it has records.

This is my code:

```
-(void)readMovesFromDatabaseWithPath:(NSString *)filePath
{
    sqlite3 *database;

    printf("Here in readMovesFromDatabaseWithPath\n");

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Now in readMovesFromDatabaseWithPath\n");

        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from moves";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatment;

        printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) ); //returns "not an error"

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatment, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"In sqlite3_prepare_v2 block\n"); //does not reach this line

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatment) == SQLITE_ROW) //Loops through the database
            {
                //Extracts the move's name
                NSString *moveName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatment, 1)];

                //Extracts the move's description
                NSString *moveDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatment, 2)];

                //Creates new move objects
                Moves *newMove = [[Moves alloc] init];
                newMove.moveName = moveName;
                newMove.moveDescription = moveDescription;
                [self.moves addObject:newMove];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatment);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the statement that prints the error into an else clause. Your program will tell you why it is failing:

```
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatment, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
       /* your code here */
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
    }
```

Most likely case is that the table `moves` does not exist.

Comment: Nvm. I placed some debug lines in my code and found out that database path was null but it was still equaling true when compared to the SQLITE_OK expression. It's kinda stupid. The problem was that I had to manually place the sqlite3 file in the project folder and then "add to existing project" via xcode. I initially made the database on my desktop and had the project in a separate folder. The "copy to folder" option works but XCode doesn't acknowledge its path for some reason. :/ Fixed it anyhow. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not assign your sqlStatement to your compiledStatment.

```
const char *compiledStatment = [sqlStatement UTF8String];
```